# When scoping the CLK and DATA lines of a PS/2 keyboard it looks... rather odd

Tags: digital-logic, oscilloscope, signal-integrity

Normally if I look at a digital signal I see a nice, relatively sharp pulse train on the screen, but when scoping the outputs of a PS/2 keyboard things get a little weird and I'm not sure what it means (though I suspect it means I've got something to learn here!)

If I don't hook the PS/2 outputs to anything other than the scope I get a rather normal looking pulse train on keypresses... it's a little odd in that it seems to slope at a small angle, but it's recognizable. However, when feeding an input line to a microcontroller (or using a 2K2 or so pull-up resistor to 5V) what you see below is what I get... (this is in AC mode for ease of display. DC mode looks similar except these oddly miniscule pulses are from 5V, though the pulses themselves are still <1 V peak-to-trough).

(*Red = DATA, Yellow = CLK*)

No matter what I do, the signal is surprisingly weak. Just for grins I started a normal pulse train out of the microcontroller and as expected it looked perfectly normal. I understand that PS/2 devices use an open-collector design, if that helps. So: what am I seeing here? And how do I get a relatively normal logic-level pulse train out of this signal?

Note: I tried another PS/2 device - same results.

Edit: updated pictures! All the outputs I got, normal-ish or not, are around 600mV peak-to-trough.

Edit 2: This all started because what should've been an extremely simple project (hook-up of a PS/2 keyboard to a microcontroller - with software applied to it and monitoring/driving the correct pins) didn't work... I was surprised at that first and foremost, and then started snooping at the signals (which I planned to do anyway AFTER it was supposed to be up and running, to learn more.) I keep thinking maybe it's the keyboard but I get the same effect from an old mouse as well (though it requires more handshaking to initialize it does at least send a clock burst on startup, and that burst is virtually the same in all characteristics as what I saw with the keyboard. The wiring seems sound and there really isn't much at all between the microcontroller and the DATA/CLK lines... it's virtually a straight shot to power and I/O.

And yet these patterns look vaguely familiar to me from a long time ago (different projects) and I suspect it'll be something simple.

Edit 3: I asked someone I know who is more analog-oriented and they think it looks an awful lot like a signal being clamped by a **diode** or such (the fact it's in a 0.6V range rather than a 5V range makes more sense in that case... now I know why it looked familiar). More later when I've tested things... might be that the cable I'm using to plug into isn't so passive after all (I thought it was... but *facepalm* I'll bet it's got a diode in it for some reason. Note it's salvaged from an old CueCat FWIW, and I am wondering if it's the splitter that's not in use that's the ultimate cause... and yes, I tested the connections and they seemed normal but I could've gotten lucky and forward-biased a hidden diode without knowing it).

**Scope output (with pull-ups, AC mode probes, each centered at 0V):**

[image: Output 1]

**Scope output (with pull-ups, DC mode probes, each centered at 5V):**

[image: Output 2]

**Scope output (direct read (no pull-ups), DC mode probes, each centered at 0V):**

[image: Output 3]

**Scope output (direct read (no pull-ups), DC mode probes, each centered at 0V) (overlay view of the signal above):**

[image: Output 4]

Comment: What voltages do you read from the plot? Also add a plot with your scope in DC-mode. Double check probe attenuator settings on both scope and probe itself. Double check if the microcontroller isn't actively pulling down the two lines.

Comment: The DC-mode one looked similarly spikey except they were relative to 5V... they were still (as above) around 600mV peak-to-trough, relative to that. Only when an output was totally disconnected from anything (no pull-ups) did it resemble the sort of pulse train I'd expect in terms of shape (though barely different in terms of the voltage p-t). And the probes and the scope were set to 1x, and probing other digital signals gives much more normal results. Since PS/2 should look like a normal digital pulse train I am for now at a loss.

Comment: The new pictures remind me of a bad ground connection somewhere.

Comment: I agree with AndrejaKo, could you double check that either of the probes' ground lead/clip is attached to the system's (keyboard's/microcontroller's) ground.

Comment: Well, the probes and the keyboard are all definitely grounded (the alternate test I did - toggling another digital line on the microcontroller at around 60 KHz - showed a very normal 5V p-p pulse train as expected (unconditioned, it even showed the slight overshoot-undershoot I'd expect to see) using the same ground connection. I *did* tie the PS/2 shield wire to ground as well... I'd think if anything that'd enhance noise rejection though.

Comment: I'd expect if the keyboard wasn't grounded this would not have worked at all anyway (and a parasitic ground path (if that's even possible with this keyboard)through either DATA or CLK would've made itself immediately evident). Since it's clearly sending unique data on keypresses I kinda think the keyboard itself it ok...

Comment: @MartyMacGyver That does sound normal. Well unfortunately, I can't do anything until I get home and try this on my scope (which won't be for 6-8 more hours).

Comment: @jippie I believe the microcontroller is acting as a pull-up. Disconnecting from that and just using normal pull-up resistors to 5V has the same effect. Only when I disconnect from both and probe the signals directly (with the probe and keyboard still grounded to each other and everything else) do I see the normal looking pulse train above (though again at that strangely low voltage - which I half-heartedly attribute to the fact PS/2 runs in open-collector mode anyway).

Comment: Can you try 10 or 20K pullup on kbd only ? Also as I recall Host data is clocked on rising edge and Target data is clocked on falling edge or visa versa.

Comment: You mean unplug CLK/DATA and instead pull them up to 5V via 10K resistors? That's exactly what I did. Same effect as if it was plugged into the microcontroller. I'm betting this will turn out to be something pretty simple... it even *looks* familiar but I'm not sure why yet.

Comment: I know I've seen similar results to the last picture when there's an open-collector involved.  It's like there's a capacitor without a decent way to discharge.  It's definitely a grounding issue but not a simple one.

Comment: @AngryEE It reminds me of relying on microcontroller internal pulls up for the whole controller, cable and keyboard. I think our thoughts are similar.

Comment: Can you make a picture of the setup? Microcontroller, power supply, attached scope probes, pull ups ...

Comment: I think I'm going to start with getting a more simple PS/2 connector and ruling out a few mechanical effects first (e.g., bad cord or socket or something). I figured this would be an obvious mistake or something but apparently not.

Comment: Its definitely a signal capture error. probe or scope ground. My TEK 210 takes clean signals ok using only one probe ground. 5V P-p with some probe calibration overshoot error. 3rd measurement down says 5.12V Pk-Pk

Comment: I'll let you know what I learn... I strongly suspect it's not the probe just because they work fine otherwise... I'm only seeing this weirdness with the PS/2 stuff. I'm eager to get home to test this out with what should be a known quantity (having the keyboard driven by a PC as you did below). I've easily seen signals like you show below... just not with my hacky little PS/2 rig yet.

Comment: @Richman See my third edit to this question... I think I know what's going on here and as I suspected it's pointing to the cable I'm using to connect the keyboard to the microcontroller. I assumed it was a passive, normal cable, salvaged though it was (I even tested all the pins to ensure it'd work). Starting to think what we see here is a diode in action (if/when I get this working I'll test that theory independently...)

Comment: it's not clipped here, but rather you are reading the leakage thru a high impedance RC circuit like my simulation which was done with ratios not absolutely same as your values. but then didoes when reverse biased are leaky caps. ( reverse biased diode might present the same signal as  Voltage divider to 10M Probe shunt load. again point to the same evidence you are not connected to a ground.

Comment: connected to any dc ground on pc is better than what you using

Comment: Yeah but my ground comes from the PC (in my case the host PC via normal USB... and all the ground paths are tied together and nothing's floating normally (the only "floating" signal I saw was when I tested without any pull-ups - as expected in an open-collector mode). The probes appear normal (the grounding is accurate and the probe comp is indeed rock-solid). Also the keyboard does work normally but I haven't opened it up. First I'm re-doing the suspect PS/2 connector and testing it more thoroughly to see if it exhibits signs of active components inside the housing).

Comment: @Richman See the answer I just posted. In effect I was reading CLK and DATA off wires that didn't even go all the way TO the keyboard, while the actual CLK and DATA wires were not connected to anything. It seems really weird to me that they would retain their distinct signal characteristics even though they weren't actually connected to the wires they were cross-talking with, and that they only had crosstalk with their counterparts (the cable is NOT twisted pair FWIW). I'd have expected them to either wash each other out and leave a much weaker, noisy, blended signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it wasn't a bad scope or loose wiring or a floating ground... it was the PS/2 cable I used to connect the keyboard connector to the rest of the equipment! It's a case of not knowing your salvaged equipment very well, along with some buried surprises in the cabling itself.

Thanks for all the discussion and suggestions, though it was ultimately a non-member who caught the similarity to diode behavior and made me suspect something unexpected was actually present *within* this cabling.

I had an old cable from a CueCat. There's [some interesting teardown info here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-and-CueCat-barcode-scanner/), though that's not exactly what I was trying to do (I don't even have the 'Cat anymore... just the wiring. Figured someday there'd be a website I could post to after I screwed up while using it. :-)

Thinking **incorrectly** that these connectors were wired in parallel, I diligently tested the bare wiring what once connected to the 'Cat against the *male* plug (it was handy.. had I had ANY suspicion I'd have tested the correct connector and none of this would've happened. Assumptions...)

I accounted for the correct pin numbering and got everything wired just right based on that... except neither DATA nor CLK actually feed through to the *female* connector (I just figured the two extra wires were unused since they didn't probe to anything). So Vcc and Gnd were fine everywhere, but the actual DATA and CLK from the keyboard were not wired to anything!

So, by rights I should've gotten nothing useful at all on the output side, since those wires weren't even connected (they were snipped short and a little staggered. However, I clearly got two non-trivial and distinct (but greatly attenuated) signals, which I diligently read and which people here tried in vain to understand. It dawned on me they might indicate a reverse-biased diode was doing the attenuation, but I'm not sure (I actually did throw a diode into the mix after it was working and it had a similar effect). I think there's some circuitry in the male connector (which has two wire bundles, one from the female PS/2 plug and one from the CueCat side). If it were simple crosstalk I'd expect the signals I saw to be even smaller, and for these signals to be jumbled together, but they were VERY distinct (had they simply been dead I would've eventually realized I needed to test the female plug and would have found my error, but the apparent presence of protection diodes in that intermediate plug threw everything off. I'll post a followup if I manage to nail that detail down - I may even cut open the connector to do it.

Edit: I just cut it open... Vcc and Gnd were indeed bonded to all three targets as expected, while DATA and CLK were run over distinct lines from the female and male connectors to the endpoint. However, **NO active or passive components were present**, debunking that theory! It must've been just enough cross-talk. Given how they were crammed into the connector it's possible they were juuuuust close enough to their respective wires to bleed only their signals, though it's weird that I was getting attenuated though distinct clock and data signals despite the fact their wires were terminating on unused ping and their wires weren't even routed to the keyboard (that part of the cord didn't even *have* these two wires I was reading!) Bizarre...

I posted this thinking it was a very simple cable... clearly it was not and I used the wrong lines but this is a good example of what can happen when there are active components hidden in an apparently innocuous connector or cable (if anyone remembers APC's serial cables, [they had hidden surprises](http://www.fatblokeracing.org/ApcupsdCableConfiguration.shtml) in the form of special resistors to keep you from just using any old serial cable for communicating with your UPS... and the old iPod cables did that as well. Proprietary Cabling 101!) That's why the signals I saw rang a bell. Hopefully this helps others who are troubleshooting weird results with an apparently normal cable assembly.

**tl;dr - Always keep the possibility of hidden components in mind when using salvaged connectors (especially if you get bizarre but strangely repeatable and well-isolated signals), and test the pins you'll actually be using, not just the ones you think are wired through!**

Here's the output I got in the end. It was identical whether the keyboard was plugged into the microcontroller, with or without pull-up resistors, or even without anything at all (just straight into the scope). It should be a nice 5V p-p signal straight out... I was wrong about these open-collector outputs having any bearing on the signal strength or shape. They were just red herrings thanks to whatever is in that splitter jack...

[image: Final test]